# C++ tstring compare

Tags: c++, string, compare, tchar

I have this variable dirpath2 where I store the deepest directory name of a path:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
tstring dirPath = destPath;
tstring dirpath2 = dirPath.substr(destPathLenght - 7,destPathLenght - 1);
```

I want to be able to compare it it another string, something like:

```
if ( _tcscmp(dirpath2,failed) == 0 )
{
...       
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. Can anyone tell me how to do this or what am I doing wrong?

Please bear in mind I know almost next to nothing about C++ and this whole thing is driving me insane.

thanx in advance

Comment: do you want to compare 2 std::string? why not use  == directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::basic_string<T>` have an overloaded `operator==`, try this:

```
if (dirpath2 == failed)
{
...
}
```

Alternatively you could do like this. As `std::basic_string<T>` doesn't have an implicit conversion operator to `const T*`, you need to use the `c_str` member function to convert to `const T*`:

```
if ( _tcscmp(dirpath2.c_str(), failed.c_str()) == 0 )
{
...
}
```

Comment: This one did the trick, thus keeping me from going insane. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using `_tcscmp` with a C++ string? Just use it's builtin equality operator:

```
if(dirpath2==failed)
{
    // ...
}
```

Have a look at the provided [comparison operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/) and [methods](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) that can be used with the STL strings.

In general, if you use C++ strings you don't need to use the C string functions; however, if you need to pass C++ strings to functions that expect C-strings you can use the [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method to get a `const` C-string with the content of the specified C++ string instance.

By the way, if you know "almost next to nothing about C++", you should *really* get a C++ book and read it, even if you come from C.

Answer (score 1):

std::basic_string has a == operator. Use the string classs template:

```
if (dirpath2 == failed)
{
...
}
```